# I have multiple lists within one big list. i need to make all of the values on the inside list besides [0] into a list of floats

Tags: python

```
with open('MONTHLY.txt') as file_string:
line_list = []
txt_list = []
key_list = []
value_list = []

for line in file_string:
    line = line.strip()
    txt_list.append(line)
for num in txt_list:
    num = num.split()
    line_list.append(num)
for i in line_list[4:267]:
    i = int(i[0])
    key_list.append(i)
for i in line_list[4:267]:
    value_list.append(i[1:])
```

sample output of `value_list`:

```
[[ '11.5', '4.4', '9.2', '4.8', '5.5', '11.8', '8.2', '14.4', '1.6', '0.9', '17.9', '13.3'],

[ '5.7', '7.6', '8.7', '15.5', '18.5', '12.7', '10.4', '24.4', '51.3', '23.8', '39.0', '41.2'],

[ '31.9', '40.3', '54.8', '53.4', '56.3', '70.7', '66.6', '92.2', '92.9', '55.5', '74.0', '81.9'],

[ '62.0', '66.3', '68.8', '63.7', '106.4', '137.7', '113.5', '93.7', '71.5', '116.7', '133.2', '84.6']]
```

what i need

```
[[11.5., 4.4, 9.2, 4.8, 5.5, 11.8, 8.2, 14.4, 1.6, 0.9, 17.9, 13.3],etc]
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the output and excepted output

Comment: the quotations for the strings if they were floats they would not be there.

Answer (score 3):

I think Julio has given an answer along the right path, but it's kind of lambda- and map-heavy.  Especially the second lambda is unnecessary...`lambda y: float(y)` is a no-op.

Here's (I think) a more concise and readable way to do it:

```
>>> my_list = [['11.5','4.4'],['5.7','7.6']]
>>> [map(float, x) for x in my_list]
[[11.5, 4.4], [5.7, 7.6]]
```

Of course, there are plenty of ways to do this, but this way also gives you the flexibility to remove the first element from the output, as was alluded to in the OP's comment:

```
>>> my_list = [['11.5','4.4'],['5.7','7.6']]
>>> [map(float, x[1:]) for x in my_list]
[[4.4], [7.6]]
```

This way you could operate on whatever slice of the original list that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a double `map` function, something like:

```
>>> my_list = [['11.5','4.4'],['5.7','7.6']]
>>> map(lambda x: map(lambda y: float(y), x), my_list)
[[11.5, 4.4], [5.7, 7.6]]
```

Your applying the second map to each list of the big list. Then, for each element of the list, your applying the `float` function, that transforms something to a float object.

More about `map` function: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map

Comment: actually the output is suppose to not print the origional [0] position like 11.5 for example. the sample code was suppose to have an extra number

Comment: if you want to apply the transformation to all the list except the first element, you can apply the `map` function to `x[1::]`